# Does ASP.NET require ActiveX or not?

Tags: asp.net

Does Asp.Net require ActiveX to make Ajax calls? I suspect it does because without setting "initialize and script activeX controls not marked as safe" in IE options ASP.NET UpdatePanels don't work. Am I correct?

**A very important edit here**

I haven't had any doubts about IE6 really. But I was able to reproduce this even on IE8 (Windows 7). Try setting IE security level to high. After that you will have to set:

- Initialize and script activeX controls not marked as safe
- Submit non-encrypted form data
- Active scripting

to be able to use Asp.NET UpdatePanel. The later two are OK, but the first one... I remind you this is IE8

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are getting this error because the scripts access the `XMLHttpRequest` object (for the AJAX requests), which was implemented via ActiveX in early versions of IE.

Because it's even checking for it, you get this alert.  No it's not required for ASP.Net, but you may have issues with partial postbacks in early versions of IE if it's disabled.

Comment: Wow, really?  Internet Explorer 6 must die.

Comment: @Dave Swersky - Yes it must, however millions of businesses have legacy internal web applications that run in IE6 some of which have no upgrade path. Consequently there will be a need for it until these applications can be upgraded/replaced allowing for newer browsers to be rolled out.

Comment: Firefox can exist along side IE6. IE6 needs to blackholed from the internet. If I absolutely had to keep IE6 due to a legacy add I'd definitely have it not able to access anything outside the corporate LAN as it's just begging your network to suffer infestation.

Comment: Actually IE8 also depends on this property.

Comment: @BenAlabaster: I happen to be dealing with just that situation at my current workplace.  Believe it or not, there are multimillion-dollar CRM systems that won't work with anything *higher* than IE6.  Sad.  @Sergej: Yes, but IE8 already has the XMLHttpRequest bits, you don't have to download them separately.

Comment: @Sergej Andrejev - window.XMLHttpRequest should work in IE8+ according to the MSDN documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535874(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Should work - YES. But the question is whether ASP.NET requires ActiveX or no to run on IE8. And as far as I can see it does.

Comment: @Sergej - It doesn't require it at all, it's just checking whether native XMLHTTP is available, as part of that check it's triggering this alert.  See here for the difference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537505(VS.85).aspx#_id

Comment: But for user this would still look like as somebody is using ActiveX component? But the worst part is that it doesn't work with HIGH security level :(

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't.

Comment: This isn't fully accurate if you take the OPs whole question into account.

Comment: Does Asp.Net require ActiveX to make Ajax calls? No.  How is this not accurate?

Comment: @Sosh - Because an ASP.NET application running in IE5/6 requires ActiveX in order to make the AJAX calls. These browsers don't have the required object in the JavaScript library to make the asynchronous calls to the server - thus without ActiveX, the Asynchronous bit of AJAX cannot be used. Which would just leave JAX.

Comment: @ BenAlabaster: But this is the case with any Ajax calls in this browser - not anything to do with ASP.NET.  If the question had been "Does IE6 require ActiveX enabled to make Ajax calls?" then I would agree with you.

Comment: @Sosh - If you want to split infinitives, be my guest.  Being pedantic about the specifics of the wording used doesn't answer the essence of what the OP is asking and that is: Does my ASP.NET web application need ActiveX in order to utilize AJAX?  Saying it doesn't require ActiveX to use AJAX is fine, but that doesn't paint the whole picture.  It'll work in modern browsers without it, but not in legacy ones.

Answer (score 2):

ActiveX and AJAX are completely unrelated.  ActiveX is a mechanism to allow full-trust apps to be delivered over the web.  AJAX stands for Asynchronous Javascript and XHTML, which is a way to update areas of a webpage without posting the whole thing back to the server.

Comment: Wrong. They are related in IE6. There is no `XMLHttpRequest` object in IE6. `JScript` (IE's JavaScript engine) forces you to create a `MSXML2.XMLHTTP` object via `ActiveXObject`. Also, the `X` in AJAX stands for `XML`

Comment: @Matt - I think the word "related" may be misleading. There's a dependence on ActiveX for sure, but the two technologies aren't related per se.

Comment: @BenAlabaster: For the purpose of this question, I guess they are related.

Answer (score 1):

Ajax uses the XMLHTTPRequest object.

Before IE 7 IE used to implement this object using ActiveX.

Firefox, Safari etc implement this as a native object. [Since IE7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537505(VS.85).aspx) the XMLHTTPRequest object is exposed as a native scripting object.

The activeX issue is a browser issue rather than an asp.net issue. So the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is no, it doesn't.  However, browser incompatibilities may mean that you require Microsoft's XmlHttp ActiveX Object [for instance older versions of IE did not support that in their implementations of JavaScript (JScript)].  Modern browsers have the XmlHttpRequest Object built into JavaScript and thus ActiveX is no longer required except for compatibility with older versions of IE.

Answer (score -1):

Using .NET Page Class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178138.aspx
You can make more standardized AJAX calls using JSON. But you would need to learn AJAX for this.

Comment: That makes no sense in the context of the question.

Comment: Also I don't see how one is more standard than another. Who says that?

Comment: I mean "more standard" as in cross browser. UpdatePanel works best in IE.